# fgetc omit characters and then assign integer

Tags: c, file-io, fgetc

I've a file data.dat

```
HI5 LO2
```

from which I want to read 5 and 2, and store them as uint16s. I've written

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned short int high;
    FILE *pFile;
    pFile = fopen("data.dat", "r");
    int c;
    while(c != 'I')
    {
        c = fgetc(pFile);
    }
    high = while(c != ' ')
    {
        c = fgetc(pFile);
    }
    printf("%i\n", high);
    if(c == ' '){puts("we read until 1st line space");}
    else{puts("we didn't read until 1st line space");}
    fclose(pFile);
    return 0;
}
```

high is assigned to a while loop because we may get bigger numbers like 10, but doing this like that gives an error. How do I got about assigning integers from values in text files?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [FAQ] soon.  I observe that you want to store values in `uint16` variables of some sort, but don't  declare any such variables.  Also, `uint16` is not a 'standard' type in the sense that Standard C (ISO/IEC 9899:2011) does not define it. It defines the related type `uint16_t` conditionally -- if a platform doesn't have 16-bit unsigned integers, it doesn't have to define it.  You do define an `unsigned short`; that is approximately equivalent to `uint16`, but it is as well to learn that a lot of programming is all about consistency.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`fscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) instead:

```
unsigned short i[2];
/* fscanf() returns number of successful assignments made,
   which must be 2 in this case. */
if (fscanf(pFile, "HI%hu LO%hu", &i[0], &i[1]) == 2)
{
}
```

If the file has multiple lines use [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read it line-by-line and use [`sscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to extract the integer values from each line.

Always check the result of IO operations, that `fopen()` does not return `NULL` for example.

Comment: `%u` expects a pointer to an `unsigned int`, not an `unsigned short`.

Comment: `%u` expects not directly the pointer to whatever, it is just an `unsigned int`, how to interpret the `unsinged int` is in the programmers hand.